# python sklearn non linear svm penalty

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using Python 2.7 with sklearn and using sklearn.svm.SVC with rbf kernel and suffer from over fitting.

I tried using the C and Gamma as explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html)
and it did not do the trick

If I understand correctly C and gamma are not l1 and l2 penalty, because C is the penalty for classifying wrong and gamma is the generalization parameter with respect to the data samples. i am looking for something that will penalize the model for complexity like l1 and l2.

i want to use regularization and l1 or l2 penalty, I found some examples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html) but when i try to use the penalty parameter with the SVC it throws and error.

```
svr_rbf = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', cache_size=1,  class_weight={1:100}, penalty='l1')
```

and get the error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thebeancounter/PycharmProjects/nlp4/try.py", line 235, in <module>
    svr_rbf = SVC(kernel='rbf', cache_size=1,  class_weight={1:100}, penalty='l1')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'penalty'
```

I know that the example is not good for this case, and i am trying to use penalty that is absent in the SVC, i am looking for the right way to do it and this is the closest i found.

looking at the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) for the SVC class i see that it has no penalty attribute

how can i use l1 and l2 penalty with rbf kernel svm or if i can't how else can i try to prevent over fitting with that model?

Comment: You get that error, because in the example you cited about the examples, they are using a [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC)

Comment: The parameter `C` is the penalty parameter of SVC

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks, i know that, i am looking for the right way to do it

Comment: @VivekKumar i edited the op, i need something that is similar to the l1 and l2 penalty... if i understand correctly c and gamma are not quite it.

Comment: Yes, thats what I wanted to convey. See the Settiing C option [here]( http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use). It says that "C corresponds to regularize more the estimation"

Comment: Also the first link you shared ([rbf svm parameters](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-rbf-parameters-py)) explains quiet nicely explain the effect of the combination of `C` and `gamma` to generalize the model and reduce overfitting.