# SVM Scikit, is it possible to change the penalty for SVC, like in LinearSVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

If not, why?

I cannot find how to change penalty of SVC: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

But, Linear SVC supports this option. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html

I don't understand why, or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think linear svc has regularization but non linear kernel doesn't.
See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407896/python-sklearn-non-linear-svm-penalty)